# can I tell certbot to use a specific DNS server?

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying to renew my lets-encrypt wildcard DNS. 
So I am at the point of

```
certbot --config-dir=certs/config --work-dir=certs/run --logs-dir=certs/log -d MYDOMAIN.com -d '*.MYDOMAIN.com' --manual --preferred-challenges dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly

Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.MYDOMAIN.com with the following value:

NZXXXLm6LL8uiiqLlqigFTLvB8KZTaFmXXXX

Before continuing, verify the record is deployed.
```

And I have setup the TXT record in my DNS host web panel. However, the DNS record seems to take time to propagate.

Is there a way to tell the `certbot` which DNS server to query? I guess this might be an attack vector so probably not but...

Doing

```
nslookup -type=TXT _acme-challenge.MYDOMAIN.com
```

won't show the new TXT record.
If i add my DNS host to the command - ie use that root provider version of the certificate:

```
nslookup -type=TXT _acme-challenge.MYDOMAIN.com NS1.101DOMAIN.COM
```

I get to see the updated records. But not sure how long I have to wait for this to filter out to normal DNS. Currently I have to leave the prompt hanging until DNS refreshes which is pretty inconvenient.

Any suggestions?

Any better way to do this as am auto-renewal? It's been only one month, and it's taken me an hour of screwing around so far today. 
Do I have to self-host my own DNS in order to be able to automate this process?

Comment: beyond this it seems that TWO TXT records are required, and the second one changes every time I run the renew script.

Comment: If you created a new record, there is no caching ("propagation") involved, it should be publicly visible within seconds or minutes. If it's not, something else is wrong.

Comment: Why is it taking so long for dns to propagate? What dns service you are using?

Comment: I'm based in China currently, so the DNS nodes probably have all kinds of censure and anti-poisoning measures not to mention more basic problems.

Comment: @DusanBajic there is the negative TTL.